# UnsafeMutablePointer in swift as replacement for properly sized C Array in Obj-C

Tags: swift, mkpolyline

How can I interact with functions in swift that used to take sized C arrays?

I read through [Interacting with C APIS](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_12) and still can't figure this out.

The documentation for the coords parameter of `func getCoordinates(_ coords:UnsafeMutablePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>,range range: NSRange)` states: "On input, you must provide a C array of structures large enough to hold the desired number of coordinates. On output, this structure contains the requested coordinate data."

I tried several things, most recently:

```
var coordinates: UnsafeMutablePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D> = nil
polyline.getCoordinates(&coordinates, range: NSMakeRange(0, polyline.pointCount))
```

Would I have to use something like:

```
var coordinates = UnsafeMutablePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>(calloc(1, UInt(polyline.pointCount)))
```

Pulling my hair out here... any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try: `var coordinates = UnsafeMutablePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>()`?

Comment: Sadly, yes. Results in: `'UnsafeMutablePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>' is not identical to 'CLLocationCoordinate2D'` Which really doesn't make any sense to me since it should be `UnsafeMutablePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>'` in the function as well.

Comment: I don't get a compiler error with `var coordinates = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()`, but the `getCoordinates` function returns nothing to `&coordinates`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Normally you can just pass an array of the required type as an in-out parameter, aka

```
var coords: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
polyline.getCoordinates(&coords, range: NSMakeRange(0, polyline.pointCount))
```

but that documentation makes it seem like a bad idea! Luckily, `UnsafeMutablePointer` provides a static `alloc(num: Int)` method, so you can call `getCoordinates()` like this:

```
var coordsPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>.alloc(polyline.pointCount)
polyline.getCoordinates(coordsPointer, range: NSMakeRange(0, polyline.pointCount))
```

To get the actual `CLLocationCoordinate2D` objects out of the mutable pointer, you should be able to just loop through:

```
var coords: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
for i in 0..<polyline.pointCount {
    coords.append(coordsPointer[i])
}
```

And since you don't want a memory leak, finish up like so:

```
coordsPointer.dealloc(polyline.pointCount)
```

---

Just remembered `Array` has a `reserveCapacity()` instance method, so a much simpler (and probably safer) version of this would be:

```
var coords: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
coords.reserveCapacity(polyline.pointCount)
polyline.getCoordinates(&coords, range: NSMakeRange(0, polyline.pointCount))
```

Comment: Who are you and why aren't we best friends.

Comment: Hey I'm here and everything but you never call.

Comment: I do have one more question: WHY would the API continue to use `UnsafeMutablePointer` instead of a good ol' optimized swift Array? Seems like a lot of additional effort for nothing.

Comment: That array is only a bad idea because it is not big enough. If you had created an array of sufficient size, e.g. `var coords: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = [CLLocationCoordinate2D](count: polyline.pointCount, repeatedValue: kCLLocationCoordinate2DInvalid)` then I don't see why you shouldn't be able to pass `&coords` as the pointer directly.

Comment: @newacct Understood, so when I was getting no result with `var coordinates = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()` it was because it needed a specified size like the old C array... duh. My question stands however, why does the API require a sized array? Is it for efficiency? Some weird need for backwards compatibility that I'm not aware of? I understand modern languages sometimes need to have interactions with parent-language elements, but still curious.

Comment: Also, dropping the type declaration is fine too: `var coords = [CLLocationCoordinate2D](count: polyline.pointCount, repeatedValue: kCLLocationCoordinate2DInvalid)`

Comment: @AndrewRobinson: The API is imported from Objective-C, and types are translated in an automated way. The Objective-C signature is `- (void)getCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D *)coords range:(NSRange)range`. In C, you cannot pass an array, only a pointer (plus, C is pass-by-value, so it wouldn't work anyway because we need the function to be able to modify the array). And a pointer doesn't have an associated size. Plus in C you cannot resize an array already allocated. In Cocoa there is NSMutableArray, but that requires elements that are objects, which CLLocationCoordinate2D is not.

Comment: Using directly the swift array and reserveCapacity I get an array :(

Comment: it will be also nice to use `defer`  for the `dealloc`:       `var startCoordinates: UnsafeMutablePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D> = UnsafeMutablePointer.alloc(step.polyline.pointCount)
                defer { startCoordinates.dealloc(step.polyline.pointCount) }`

Comment: @Ben Should I do something like `coordsPointer.dealloc(polyline.pointCount)` and then `free(coordsPointer)` in the `deinit()` func?

Answer (score 0):

extension wrapper for @Nate Cook's awesome answer, cannot get the `reserveCapacity()` version to work, it keep returning empty object.

```
import MapKit

extension MKPolyline {

    var coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] {
        get {
            let coordsPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>.allocate(capacity: pointCount)
            var coords: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
            for i in 0..<pointCount {
                coords.append(coordsPointer[i])
            }
            coordsPointer.deallocate(capacity: pointCount)
            return coords
        }
    }
}
```