# Convert UnsafeMutablePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D> to [CLLocationCoordinate2D] in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I write an app in Swift and is bridging some Objective-C code. One of these classes has a method that looks like this: `+ (CLLocationCoordinate2D *)polylineWithEncodedString:(NSString *)encodedString;`.

In Swift, it said this method returns a `UnsafeMutablePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>`. What I want is a Swift array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

What obviously doesn't work, but I tried, is this:

```
let coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = TheClass.polylineWithEncodedString(encodedString)
```

which will give me the following error:

```
'UnsafeMutablePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>' is not convertible to '[CLLocationCoordinate2D]'
```

Is it somehow possible to convert this `UnsafeMutablePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>` to a `[CLLocationCoordinate2D]`? Or should I take a different approach?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UnsafeMutablePointer in swift as replacement for properly sized C Array in Obj-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25560751/unsafemutablepointer-in-swift-as-replacement-for-properly-sized-c-array-in-obj-c)

Comment: This seems to be going the opposite way from [] to UnsafeMutablePointer<>, instead of UnsafeMutablePointer<> to [].

Comment: @ViktorNilsson: Do you know how *many* elements are returned via the pointer? Where is the array allocated and who is responsible for freeing it? – Passing a Swift array to be filled by the ObjC function (as in the referenced thread) would be easier in terms of memory management.

Comment: @MartinR: Not easily, and then it is the memory management as you say. I guess I will have to try to pass the data in a different way. Do you have any idea what would be the best way to pass multiple structs, from ObjC, to Swift-code?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the *memory* property of the UnsafeMutablePointer, which is the data behind the pointer. But keep in mind that *UnsafeMutablePointer < CLLocationCoordinate2D >* will return one CLLocationCoordinate2D, not an array, just as declared in the obj c function.

```
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = TheClass.polylineWithEncodedString(encodedString).memory
```