# Draw a line on Mapkit using list of coordinates

Tags: ios, swift3, location, mapkit, mkpolyline

I have an array of coordinate objects, and want to connect these (in the order they are) as a Polyline in Mapkit in Swift 3. How do I go about doing this? Here is my data structure

```
List<Location> (
    [0] Location {
        lat = 37.33477977;
        long = -122.03369603;
    },
    [1] Location {
        lat = 37.33477977;
        long = -122.03369603;
    },
    [2] Location {
        lat = 37.33477977;
        long = -122.03369603;
    },
    [3] Location {
        lat = 37.33305632;
        long = -122.05318781;
    },
    [4] Location {
        lat = 37.33298105;
        long = -122.0535463;
    }
)
```

The previous discussions on this topic are now outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert it to an array of `[CLLocation]` have a look at this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24798737/how-to-use-mkpolylineview-in-swift):

```
var locations = [CLLocation(latitude: 37.582691, longitude: 127.011186), CLLocation(latitude: 37.586112,longitude: 127.011047), CLLocation(latitude: 37.588212, longitude: 127.010438)]
        var coordinates = locations.map({(location: CLLocation) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D in return location.coordinate})
        var polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &coordinates, count: locations.count)
```

Comment: Swift has been updated since that answer, and the code in the question doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I've submitted an updated edit to the linked question with Swift 3 compatible code.

Comment: The documentation makes reference to `init(coordinates coords: UnsafePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>, count: Int)`. Seems to be the same as this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25560751/unsafemutablepointer-in-swift-as-replacement-for-properly-sized-c-array-in-obj-c